# How do mail filter applications work to move messages between mailboxes?

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I want to create a spam filter similar to Boxtrapper, SpamArrest, Gafana, and Boxbe. I need to move the message to a different folder depending on custom rules. I looked into the following, but it's not clear how to indicate to Postfix to move the message. Most filter protocols only allow to accept or reject the message, without any way to move messages. I saw Sieve allows rules processing to move mail, but doesn't allow running custom programs.

- Milter: http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html - No way to move messages. Only return action of accept, reject, tempfail, or quarantine.
- Before-queue filter: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html - No way to move messages. Complicated protocol (ESMTP).
- After-queue filter: http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html - No way to move messages.
- Sieve: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve - A Sieve rules language implementation for Dovecot called Pigeonhole, but doesn't allow running programs.

Maybe there is a background process scanning the mailbox to send the challenge/response? It seems like it would be more efficient as a hook-based filter rather than polling based.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Sieve extprograms](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/Extprograms) plugin to allow my Sieve scripts to invoke a custom program. I use that functionality for email notification via Growl:

```
if anyof (true)
{
        pipe :try :copy "growlmail";
}
```

For spam classification, I use Spamassassin as a [postfix content_filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html). It re-writes the email subject lines of spam messages (to something like `****SPAM(12.5)**** This One Weird Trick....`). I'll then have Sieve refile based on that:

```
if anyof (header :contains "Subject" "****SPAM")
{
        fileinto "spam";
        stop;
}
```